# Odoo 14: Add a section functionality in tree view

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-14

I need **add a section** functionality like sales > quotation view has, in one of my tree views. [image: Sample picture from sales view].

Code of my **view** is something like this:

```
<record id="view_qualification_form_inh" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">hr.applicant.form</field>
    <field name="model">hr.applicant</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_recruitment.hr_applicant_view_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <xpath expr="//field[@name = 'description']" position="after">

            <notebook>
                <page string="Qualification">
                    <field name="qualification_lines">
                        <tree editable="bottom">
                            <control>
                                <create name="add_line_control" string="Add a line"/>
                                <create name="add_section_control" string="Add a section"
                                        context="{'default_display_type': 'line_section'}"/>
                            </control>
                            <field name="qualification_type_id"/>
                            <field name="qualification_type_line_id" domain="[('qualification_type_id','=',qualification_type_id)]"/>
                            <field name="score" />

                        </tree>
                    </field>
                    <group class="oe_subtotal_footer">
                        <field name="avg_score" class="oe_subtotal_footer_separator"/>
                    </group>
                </page>
            </notebook>
        </xpath>

    </field>
</record>
```

Code of my **model**:

```
class HrApplicant(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.applicant'

     qualification_lines = fields.One2many('hr.applicant.qualification', 'qualification_data',)
     avg_score = fields.Float(compute='compute_score_average',store=True,index=True, string='Average Score')

    display_type = fields.Selection([
    ('line_section', "Section"),
    ('line_note', "Note")], default=False, help="Technical field for UX purpose.")

class Qualification(models.Model):
     _name = 'hr.applicant.qualification'
     _description = 'Applicant Qualification'

     qualification_data = fields.Many2one('hr.applicant', string='Qualification')

     qualification_type_id = fields.Many2one('hr.applicant.qualification.rule', string='Qualification Type')
     qualification_type_line_id = fields.Many2one(related='qualification_type_id.qualification_type_line_id')
     score = fields.Float(related='qualification_type_line_id.score')
```

The thing is, I got a **add a section** option but it is working same like default "add a line". [image: My achieved results]

I know it has lot of things to do with python code, even tried to get it from sales' addon but it has very complex structure. I am a beginner, so if anyone can help me out with code or at-least steps for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `qualification_lines` widget attribute to `section_and_note_one2many` and define the `display_type` in the applicant qualification model instead of the `applicant` model,  it will be used to check if you need to add a section (***help***: *Technical field for UX purpose*).

In the following example the section text will be stored in the `name` field:

***View definition:***

```xml
<field name="qualification_lines"
       widget="section_and_note_one2many">
    <tree editable="bottom">
        <control>
            <create name="add_line_control" string="Add a line"/>
            <create name="add_section_control" string="Add a section"
                    context="{'default_display_type': 'line_section'}"/>
        </control>
        <field name="name" widget="section_and_note_text" optional="show"/>
        <field name="display_type" invisible="1"/>
        <field name="score"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

***Model definition:***

```
class Qualification(models.Model):
    _name = 'hr.applicant.qualification'
    _description = 'Applicant Qualification'

    name = fields.Char(required=True)
    display_type = fields.Selection([
        ('line_section', "Section"),
        ('line_note', "Note")], default=False, help="Technical field for UX purpose.")

    qualification_data = fields.Many2one('hr.applicant', string='Qualification')
```

Comment: One thing, name column is constantly showing in tree view, but it isn't supposed to. As soon you click on **add a section** it should get displayed and saved.

Comment: The renderer will check if there is a [name](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/account/static/src/js/section_and_note_fields_backend.js#L31), set the colspan, and return it so if you add a field named `name` it will be used to set the section. You can use developer tools to check to the field used to set the section in sale orders.