# How can i add add line and Add section in notebook in odoo13?

Tags: python, xml, postgresql, odoo

I try to add the `Add a line` and `Add a section` in the notebook section in odoo13. how can I add these features in odoo13 in XML?

**Python code:**

```
class productline(models.Model):  
    _name = 'product.line'

    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='product')
```

**View definition:**

```
<notebook>
    <page string="Indent details">
        <field name="roni">
            <tree editable="bottom">
                <field name="product_id"/>
            </tree>
       </field>
   </page>
</notebook>
```

Comment: I added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64520995/odoo-14-add-a-section-functionality-in-tree-view) for Odoo 14, which is also working for Odoo-13.

Comment: I can't save the field value of add section field in my database. It will automatically pop up a field when click it then automatically close the field. How can i recover from it. Can you explain it?

Comment: Did you add a `name` field next to the `display_type` field?

Comment: I added the name field before display_type like as you declared in your script. can you please give me the full code of it. So that i can understand it properly. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The full code is in my answer linked in the first comment, first, you need to set the widget attribute to `section_and_note_one2many` then, add the ``control`` section, and finally define the two special fields `display_type` and `name` and add them to the view definition inside the `tree`, the `display_type` should be hidden  (`<field name="display_type" invisible="1"/>`) and you can set two more options on the `name` field (`<field name="name" widget="section_and_note_text" optional="show"/>`).  The `display_type` and `name` fields should be defined next to the `product_id` field.

Comment: Did you succeed to add the section and note?

Comment: no. i follow your process but can't complete it..

Comment: Please update your code and I will test it.

Comment: complete your process but not work. ORM code:                                                            class productline(models.Model):
 _name = 'product.line'
 name = fields.Char(required=True)
 display_type = fields.Selection([
  ('line_section', "Section"),
  ('line_note', "Note")], default=False, help="Technical field for UX purpose.")
 product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='product')

Comment: view.xml code:                 <field name="roni" widget="section_and_note_one2many">

                                    <tree editable="bottom">
                                    <control>
                           <create name="add_line_control" string="Add a line"/>
                           <create name="add_section_control" string="Add a section" context="{'default_display_type': 'line_section'}"/>
                                    </control>

Comment: <field name="product_id"/>

                                      <field name="name" widget="section_and_note_text" optional="show"/>
                                        <field name="display_type" invisible="1"/>

Comment: when i open add section field and write something after that other module code will automatically save it. But in my code showing a pop up window then if click ok on it. then it automatically delete the add section value. So should i will do?

Comment: I tested your code and there is no popup, your code works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir for providing me your time. But I also check today by following this same code but it currently shows up the same error. is there any problem with my version code or ORM design? I don't know what I will do to recover this.

Comment: What error? Try to check the error log.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```html
      <page string="Indent details">
                            <field name="roni" widget="section_and_note_one2many">

                                <tree editable="bottom">



                                    <field name="product_id"/>

                                    
                                </tree>

                            </field>


                    </page>

                </notebook>
```